# Llamar una callback a un fragment desde un adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, constructor

Espero me puedan ayudar,llevo semanas buscando una solución y solo me falta esto para terminar un proyecto.
Quiero llamar a un metodo.(UpdateItemcount) pero no puedo hacerlo desde mi adapter.
he intentado de varias formas pero implica cambiar el constructor que tengo y termina sin funcionar.

este es mi fragment

```
public class Selection2 extends Fragment implements Actualizarvalor {

TextView catidadproductos, valortotal;
RecyclerView recycler_cart;
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;
List<Cart> cartList;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_selection2, container, false);
    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    catidadproductos=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cant_productoss);
    valortotal=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.total);
    recycler_cart = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_cart3);
    recycler_cart.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recycler_cart.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initDB();
    loadCartItems();
    catidadproductos.setText(String.valueOf (Common.cartRepository.countCartItems()));
    valortotal.setText(String.valueOf(Common.cartRepository.sumPrice()));
    return v;
}

private void loadCartItems() {
    compositeDisposable.add(
            Common.cartRepository.getCartItems()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Cart>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(List<Cart> carts) throws Exception {
                            displayCartItem(carts);
                        }
                    })
    );
}
private void displayCartItem(List<Cart> carts ) {
    Cartadapter2 cartadapter = new Cartadapter2(getActivity(),carts);
    recycler_cart.setAdapter(cartadapter);
}
 @Override
public void updateItemCount(boolean b) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Datos de compra actualizados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private void initDB() {
    Common.edmtRoomDatabase = EDMTRoomDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
    Common.cartRepository = CartRepository.getInstance(CartDataSource.getInstance(Common.edmtRoomDatabase.cartDAO()));
    Common.favoriteRepository = FavoriteRepository.getInstance(FavoriteDataSource.getInstance(Common.edmtRoomDatabase.favoriteDAO()));
}
}
```

y este es mi adapter

```
 Actualizarvalor callback;
Context context;
List<Cart> cartList;
public Cartadapter2(Context context, List<Cart> cartList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cartList = cartList;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item,parent,false);
    return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CartViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(cartList.get(position).link)
            .into(holder.img_product);
    holder.txt_product_name.setText(cartList.get(position).name);
    holder.descripcion.setText(cartList.get(position).descripcion);
    holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(cartList.get(position).id));
    holder.txt_price.setText(new StringBuilder("$").append(cartList.get(position).price));
    holder.txt_countervalue.setText(cartList.get(position).amount);
    holder.btPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cart tempObj = cartList.get(position);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(holder.txt_countervalue.getText().toString());
            number++;
            holder.txt_countervalue.setText(Integer.toString(number));
            callback.updateItemCount(true);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cartList.size();
}
class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
   public ImageView img_product;
   public ImageView btPlus,btMinus;
   public TextView txt_product_name, txt_price,txt_countervalue, descripcion,id;
   public CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img_product = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_product);
        txt_countervalue = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.counterValue);
        txt_product_name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
        txt_price=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
        descripcion=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_description);
        btPlus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.botonmas);
        btMinus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.botonmenos);
        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idcartitem);
    }
}
}
```

Tambien creé una interfaz,

```
public interface Actualizarvalor {
void updateItemCount(boolean b);
}
```

No logro hacer el callback en el evento onclick de mi ´btnplus´ en el adapter sin cambiar mi constructor,
Por favor su ayuda con este tema, me quedé atascado en esto ya unas semanas.

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 1):

En el `adapter` te falta meter el `callback` en el contructor o un `setter`.

```
public Cartadapter2(Context context, List<Cart> cartList, Actualizarvalor callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cartList = cartList;
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Y en el `fragment`.

```
private void displayCartItem(List<Cart> carts ) {
    Cartadapter2 cartadapter = new Cartadapter2(getActivity(),carts, this);
    recycler_cart.setAdapter(cartadapter);
}
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS ::ME FUNCIONÓ

Answer (score 0):

El callback no se inicializa por ello es que no hace nada, incluso es muy posible arroje un NullPointerException, para evitar eso tienes que darle memoria, en tu Adapter debes agregar el siguiente metodo:

```
public Cartadapter2 setActualizarValor(Actualizarvalor actualizarvalor){
    this.callback = actualizarvalor;
    return Cartadapter2.this;
}
```

Y en tu Fragment Selection2 edita el metodo displayCardItem:

```
private void displayCartItem(List<Cart> carts ) {
    Cartadapter2 cartadapter = new Cartadapter2(getActivity(),carts)
            .setActualizarValor(Selection2.this);
    recycler_cart.setAdapter(cartadapter);
}
```